# Is the sealed book of Dan. 12:4 the same as the open book in Rev. 10?

Tags: word-study, revelation

The book that Daniel was told to seal, is that the same as the little book that was opened in the angel’s hand in Rev. 10?

Daniel 12:4 reads:

> But thou, O Daniel, shut up the words, and seal the book, even to the time of the end: many shall run to and fro, and knowledge shall be increased.

Revelation 10:2,10,11 says:

> And he had in his hand a little book open: and he set his right foot upon the sea, and his left foot on the earth,
>
> And I took the little book out of the angel's hand, and ate it up; and it was in my mouth sweet as honey: and as soon as I had eaten it, my belly was bitter.
> And he said unto me, Thou must prophesy again before many peoples, and nations, and tongues, and kings.

I find it interesting that the one is closed and the other opened.

Comment: It sound interesting because in both chapters you have the instruction to keep sealed part of the prophecy. Daniel was told to seal the book and John was told not to write what the 7 thunders uttered.

Comment: It is true that this connection is often made.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of the "booklet" of Rev 10 has occasioned many theories.  Before answering the question, let me observe several things about this "booklet".

- the Greek word, βιβλαρίδιον biblaridion, occurs nowhere else in the NT and denotes a small book, or, "booklet".
- the verb, ἠνεῳγμένον (Rev 10:2) means "having been opened"; that is, when John sees the booklet, it had just been opened at whatever time the prophecy depicts.
- no other scroll or book is described this way, ie, both small and just having been opened.

Among the suggestions for the identity of this book are the following:

- the Bible as per Barnes, et al. [However, the Bible is not a small book and never described as such and contains many books.]
- The New Testament as per Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary, Bede, etc. [However, the NT is not a small book and never described as such and contains many books, none of which was ever sealed.]
- The book of Rev 5:1 as per Matthew Poole.  [However, this is explicitly described as a book and not a little book and the "booklet of Rev 10:2 appears to distinguish the book of Rev 5:1 from the booklet of Rev 10:2. However, this does not prelude the possibility that the booklet is a small portion of the book of Rev 5:1.  If so, we have no way of knowing what portion.]
- The preaching of Christ as per Gill, et al. [However, the preaching of Christ is contained in four books of the Gospels and not a single book; and these were never sealed.]
- The book of Revelation itself.  [However, this cannot be the case as the book of Revelation is explicitly said to have never been sealed, Rev 22:10.]
- The Book of Daniel - this is certainly a small book that was sealed, Dan 8:26, 12:4.  Indeed, it was the only book of the Bible that is described as being sealed.

In favor of the last identification, the book of Revelation often alludes to the book of Daniel and often quotes some of its passages (as is well known, especially the angel with the raised hand!)  Further, the purpose of the "eating the booklet" appears to enable the eater to "prophesy again about many peoples and nations and tongues and kings" (Rev 10:10, 11), about which the book of Daniel has much to say.

The idea of eating a prophetic book is taken directly from the inauguration of the prophet Ezekiel in Eze 2:9 - 3:3 -

> Then I looked and saw a hand reaching out to me, and in it was a
> scroll, which He unrolled before me. And written on the front and back
> of it were words of lamentation, mourning, and woe.
>
> “Son of man,” He said to me, “eat what you find here. Eat this scroll,
> then go and speak to the house of Israel.” So I opened my mouth, and
> He fed me the scroll. “Son of man,” He said to me, “eat and fill your
> stomach with this scroll I am giving you.” So I ate, and it was as
> sweet as honey in my mouth.

Finally, let me observe that the chain of Revelation, from God to John, described in Rev 1:1-3 appears complete with John receiving the "booklet" in Rev 10:1.

Answer (score 0):

The open little book in Revelation 10:2, should refer to the book that sealed with seven seals in Revelation 5:1. After the Lamb opened all the seals, the book was opened.

Now, would the sealed book in Revelation 5:1 same as the sealed book in Daniel 12:4? My answer is "No".

The sealed book in Revelation 5:1 is said only the Lamb is worthy to open its seals. The words in the book were absolutely hidden. Whereas the sealed book in Daniel 12:4 (KJV) read

> 4 But thou, O Daniel, shut up the words, and seal the book, even to
> the time of the end: many shall run to and fro, and knowledge shall be
> increased.

The second half of the verse didn't mean the words in the book was totally hidden. The Living Bible has this translation

> 4 “But Daniel, keep this prophecy a secret; seal it up so that it will not be understood until the end times, when travel and education shall be vastly increased!”

The verse Daniel 12:4 is better to understand as;

- But Daniel, keep silent about the things when you write them down on the book. Do not give explanation to them. Many people will try to interpret it and though a vast knowledge had been collecting, they all go in vain. For the truth will only be seen until the end times.

So the sealed book of Daniel only mean **the truth** of the book was sealed but not the book was sealed, as the book in Revelation.

Answer (score -1):

**No, the book of Daniel is not the same as the boom of Revelation**, since one is the book of the Book of Daniel and one is the Book of Revelation and if you check your Bible you can see they're different.

I'm being facetious, and the link is there - Revelation references Daniel. The two works are both visionary and apocalyptic.

**How do we know the sealed book is the Book of Daniel?**

> But thou, O Daniel, shut up the words, and seal the book, even to the
> time of the end: many shall run to and fro, and knowledge shall be
> increased.

It is a generally accepted fact - known to the first readers - that the Book of Daniel first came to general notice long after Daniel had died, and indeed after many of its prophecies had already come true. "the words in question" are the apocalyptic vision of Daniel.

**The Book in Revelation is the Book in Revelation**

What does John do to the open book? He eats it. This is a reference to [Ezekiel 3:3](https://biblehub.com/ezekiel/3-3.htm)

> And he said unto me, Son of man, cause thy belly to eat, and fill thy bowels with this roll that I give thee. Then did I eat it; and it was in my mouth as honey for sweetness.

These are - in Revelation and Ezekiel - the words in question to be published.

**And Revelation and John are different?**

Daniel was sealed for a long time between vision and publication. However, Revelation was released straight away (Indeed to a trade route to guarantee fast transmission.). [Revelation 22:10](https://biblehub.com/revelation/22-10.htm) tells us - in deliberate contrast to Daniel:

> And he saith unto me, Seal not the sayings of the prophecy of this book: for the time is at hand.

This is fairly clearly the opposite directions to Daniel 12:4.

**In conclusion,** both books are the apocalyptics writing and their being shut and closed demonstrate the differences in speed to publication - and nearness to the events predicted.